# How to get max value by comparing dual y-axis in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with dual y-axis, how can i get the min and max value from both?

```
load: function () {
      var series = this.series,
      max = series[0].dataMax,
      min = series[0].dataMin;

      series.forEach(function (serie) {
          if (serie.dataMax > max) {
          max = serie.dataMax;
      }

      if (serie.dataMin < min) {
          min = serie.dataMin;
      }
});

 this.yAxis[0].update({
     min: min,
     max: max
 });
```

I am trying the method above, but it will only get either one side got max value and update the axis value.

How can i make both y axis using the same max value?

Answer (score 0):

To **get** min/max values from an axis, use [`getExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#getExtremes) which returns an [`ExtremesObject`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.ExtremesObject). The `ExtremesObject` has the following properties:

> dataMax, dataMin, max, min, userMax, userMin

If you want to **set** a new min/max value you should use [`setExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes)

> setExtremes( [newMin] [, newMax] [, redraw] [, animation] [, eventArguments])
>
> Set the minimum and maximum of the axes after render time. If the startOnTick and endOnTick options are true, the minimum and maximum values are rounded off to the nearest tick. To prevent this, these options can be set to false before calling setExtremes. Also, setExtremes will not allow a range lower than the minRange option, which by default is the range of five points.

So the get the min and max from both axis, you could do something like this for the min value (if you want to tailor your view to the data and not manually set extremes):

```
let firstAxisExtremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes(),
secondAxisExtremes = chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes(),
min, max;
if(firstAxisExtremes.dataMin <= secondAxisExtremes.dataMin) {
  min = firstAxisExtremes.dataMin
} else {
  min = secondAxisExtremes.dataMin
}
```

**API references:** [`getExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#getExtremes), [`setExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes), [`ExtremesObject`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.ExtremesObject)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use your current code and set `yAxis.linkedTo` property:

> ...
>
> When an axis is linked to a master axis, it will take the same
>   extremes as the master, but as assigned by min or max or by
>   setExtremes. (...)

```
yAxis: [{}, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    opposite: true
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n5bzrqs8/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo